# Vertically Resizable QTableView in Qt5

Tags: qt, resize, qt5, qt-creator, qtablewidget

I need to make a `QTableWidget` widget vertically resizable by mouse
Actually I need user be able to drag top edge of widget and resize it vertically.

How can I do this in Qt5/QCreator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QSplitter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#details) class is what you are looking for.

It lets the user control the size of the widgets that have been added to it by dragging the boundary between them. You can add widgets to a `QSplitter` using [`insertWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#insertWidget) or [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#addWidget).

Here is a minimal example:

[image: Example Screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //create a vertically resizable splitter
    QSplitter sp(Qt::Vertical);
    QTableWidget tableWidget;
    tableWidget.setRowCount(10);
    tableWidget.setColumnCount(2);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            tableWidget.setItem(i, j, 
                                new QTableWidgetItem(QString("item(%0, %1)")
                                                     .arg(i+1).arg(j+1)));
        }
    }
    QTextEdit textEdit;
    //add resizable widgets to splitter
    sp.addWidget(&textEdit);
    sp.addWidget(&tableWidget);
    sp.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```